# How to set environment attribute dynamically in a workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

In the settings of my repository I created 2 environments: development and production. I also have 2 branches of the same name. I want my workflow to execute in the corresponding environment (so as to grab the correct git secrets).

This is what I have:

```
jobs:
  branch-based-execution:
    name: Run external workflow
    environment: ${{ github.ref }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Echo env var
        env:
          my_var: ${{ secrets.my_var }}
        shell: bash
        run: echo $my_var
```

However, I get the following error on the environment line:

> Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within expression: github.ref

Looks like I can't use github context to set the environment attribute. Is there a way to set the environment of the workflow dynamically? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by two environments within your GitHub repo? FYI: The `github.ref` confused me because I thought you were referring to `GITHUB_REF` from default environment variables: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: @astrochun Yeah, if you go to Settings > Environments within your repo you can create new environments. I created two of those. These environments allow you to set git secrets to specific environments, and then in your workflow you can reference the environment name and have access to those specific secrets.(https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environments)

I used github.ref instead of GITHUB_REF because GITHUB_REF is only available once the runner is up (because it is an env var). For everything else, you have to use github context vars, like github.ref

Comment: Ah, in that case, I think you should just provide the environment name. See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment

Comment: Yes but I have 2 branches and I want to have the same workflow file in both branches. That's why I want to put a dynamic value into the environment name, but it doesn't accept it.

Comment: If you want it in the same workflow file then you might consider using `if` statement with `github.ref`. And set your environment to the appropriate name. That refers to e.g., `ref/heads/main`. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts.

Comment: Do you have an example on how I could that? I tried for example

env: development
if: github.ref == 'ref/heads/development'

env: production
if: github.ref == 'ref/heads/production'

But there the problem is that I can't put 2 'environment' attributes nor 2 'if' attributes under the same level in YAML (or in github actions for that matter), and I do want the 2 possible environments to apply to the same level in the workflow

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of an example. You might try two separate workflows (triggering on separate `branches`). At least that would work. I know it won't be as clean as you want. If you can provide your full workflow, that could be helpful for someone with more experience than I. I have not tried `environment` settings. I noticed that you used `env` in your last response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can set it dynamically](https://github.community/t/how-to-set-environment-attribute-dynamically-in-a-workflow/163240), you just have to specify that you are setting the name

```
jobs:
  branch-based-execution:
    name: Run external workflow
    environment:
      name: ${{ github.ref }}
```